# Is it possible to use jupyter_contrib_nbextensions in nbviewer?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

*Is it possible to use [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) extension like "[Collapsible Headings](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/collapsible_headings/readme.html)" in [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/)?*

I've managed to use it locally by doing the following steps:

```
# Install Jupyterextension package
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install

# Install configurator and enable configurator
pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable
```

Then I've just enabled "Collapsible Headings" in nbextensions configurator panel.

But when I've uploaded the notebook to the GitHub and then tried to open it with [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) or [mybinder](https://mybinder.org/) it launched the notebook but without collapsible heading support.

*How can I "tell" nbviewer or mybinder that I need them to use "Collapsible Headings" extensions?* I've updated my requirements.txt file and added jupyter_contrib_nbextensions dependency to it but it looks like it is not enough...

Comment: Have you looked at https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#executing-post-build-commands . 
They state  "It is also useful for activating notebook extensions you installed via a requirements.txt directive earlier.
Take a look at the binder-examples/jupyter-extension repository to see an example."

Comment: @AdrienPacifico thank you for the hint! It works for mybinder by using the `postBuild` file in the root of the repository with extension activation instructions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following @AdrienPacifico and [mybinder documentation](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#executing-post-build-commands) suggestions I've managed to have [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) installed and activated for both - my local Jupyter server **and** for [mybinder](https://mybinder.org/) server by simply putting all extension activation instructions into `postBuild` file in the root of my repository.

Here are examples of `requirements.txt` and `postBuild` files that activate [collapsible_headings](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/collapsible_headings/readme.html) extension:

**requirements.txt**

```
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.5.0
```

**postBuild**

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable collapsible_headings/main
```

After launching a repository with these files in mybinder the collapsible_headings extensions will be activated automatically for every users.

The only question I still have though is to how we can preserve the same look-and-feel for [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) also...